# How dangerous is the Mercury-Thallium filled thermometer?

Tags: safety

1. What's the amount of Mercury and Thallium in a typical low-temperature thermalmeter?
2. How poisonous is Thallium when bounded with Mercury?

Answer (score 3):

The lowest eutectic in the Hg-Tl system occurs at 8.6 at.% Tl at 213K (see [W. Gierlotka et al., CALPHAD 30425-430 (2006)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364591606000599)). This is about 21K lower than the freezing point of pure Hg.

For toxicity, refer to an SDS (MSDS) or ask you local ES&H or industrial hygiene professional.